# Expanding Environmental Variable using CSV file into Powershell script

Tags: powershell, csv, environment-variables, robocopy

i am trying to create a backup script with csv file which will contain all the local (where backup will be stored) and backup (folder to backup) loaction and run robocopy to copy files from backup to local folder. i want to import environmental variable from csv file that are used for default folders (e.g. env:APPDATA) as location to be use for backing up some files and folders in user documents or pulbic documents. When i use the env variable directly or use full path address in the script the copy action works fine.

```
robocopy "&env:localappdata\steam" "$backup"
```

but when import from csv, the script does not see it as env variable. robocopy shows the error because it picks up the locations like this

```
 Source : C:\WINDOWS\system32\$env:LOCALAPPDATA\steam\
     Dest : D:\backup\steam\
```

Below is the full code i am using.

```
$path = "$PSScriptRoot\backup\"
$locations = import-csv "$PSScriptRoot\backup\local.csv" -Delimiter "," -Header 'Local','Backup','Display' | Select-Object Local,Backup,display

foreach($location in $locations){
 
    $source = $location.Local
    $source = $source.ToString()

    $destination = $location.Backup
    $destination = $destination.tostring()
   
   
    $Name = $location.Display
    $Name = $name.tostring()

    Write-host "Copying $Name, please wait...." -foregroundColor Yellow
    robocopy "$destination" "$path$source" \s \e
}
```

And my CSV file looks like this

> Steam, $env:LOCALAPPDATA\steam, Steam files Backup

Answer (score 0):

As you have added a path in the csv as `$env:LOCALAPPDATA\steam`, and knowing that whatever you read from file using `Import-Csv` is a **string**, you need to use regex to convert the `$env:VARNAME` into `%VARNAME%` in order to be able to resolve that environment variable into a path.

Instead of

```
$source = $source.ToString()
```

do this

```
$source = [Environment]::ExpandEnvironmentVariables(($source -replace '\$env:(\w+)', '%$1%'))
```

`$source` wil now have a valid path like `C:\Users\Aman\AppData\Local\Steam`

Do the same with `$destination`

Regex details:

```
\$             Match the character “$” literally
env:           Match the characters “env:” literally
(              Match the regular expression below and capture its match into backreference number 1
   \w          Match a single character that is a “word character” (letters, digits, etc.)
      +        Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
)
```

P.S. Instead of combining a path with  string concatenation like you do in `"$path$source"`, it is much safer to use the [Join-Path](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/join-path) cmdlet for that

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thnks